# Windows Azure DateTime Now Off By 1 day Compared to Local

Tags: azure

So I have been trying to figure out this problem for the past 4 hours. DateTime.Now on Windows Azure is 1/10/2013 Vs Local Time is 1/09/2013. I have tried everything in the book to get it aligned calling DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), doing UTC but I still can't solve the problem.

Comment: What timezone you're in? In Windows Azure everything's in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private DateTime ConvertToCentral()
        {
            DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
                 DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
            return cstTime;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

answer is same as Gaurav posted - Azure servers operate on UTC (Greenwich Mean Time), not your local time.  For example, Arizona is UTC - 7 hours, so we add 7 hours to local time to get UTC.  The Azure portal and browser may adjust some times to your local time, but when using DateTime.Now in code, you need to use DateTime.Now.UTC - if you want to adjust for user display for an app running in Azure, then add a ServiceConfiguration setting for TimeZoneOffset (i.e. -7) and display DateTime.Now.AddHours(TimeZoneOffset).

Answer (score 0):

Currently Windows Azure VMs use UTC and even if they didn't you should not expect that they use the same timezone as you do.

In distributed applications you'll save a lot of a hassle if you use UTC as often as possible and in cases where you can't use UTC you either use UTC together with local time or local time alone, but each time you use local time you should know specifically which timezone you're in.

If you ignore these considerations you can just as well [find yourself in year 2555 (not a joke - that's for real)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13118178/57428).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure machines are yours for the using so if you want a different time zone, go right ahead and set it.

The easiest approach is to create a very simple startup task and use **tzutil**, the Windows Time Zone Utility. We use the following:

```
tzutil /s "GMT Standard Time"
```

This is installed by default only on the Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2012 images.

Full details are here: http://wely-lau.net/2011/06/26/setting-timezone-in-windows-azure-3/