# What effect does "formatting provider" ("culture") have on Guid formatting?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, guid

I'm debugging some "impossible" issues in C# code and it looks like maybe `Guid` is sometimes converted to string in some unexpected way. Perhaps something similar to [suddenly getting year 2555 as current year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13118178/57428)  (Thai Solar Calendar).

Code converts `Guid` variables into strings using `.ToString()` calls without parameters. I see that `Guid` has this version of `ToString()` too:

```
public string ToString (string format, IFormatProvider provider);
```

and technically I could pass `InvariantCulture` as second parameter. However I don't see any documentation on how `provider` affects the formatting result.

Would that have any effect? How does the `provider` parameter affect `Guid` formatting?

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#System_Guid_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) are quite clear on this - _"The provider parameter is reserved for future use and does not contribute to the execution of this method. You can pass null in the method call."_

Comment: And: _"Because the provider parameter is ignored, you cannot use it to provide a custom formatting solution. To represent a Guid value as a string in a format that isn't supported by the standard GUID format strings, call the `String.Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])` method with a provider object that implements both the `ICustomFormatter` and `IFormatProvider` interfaces."_

Comment: What is the actual question? What is the unexpected behaviour you encountered? As for Year 2555, it was neither unexpected nor sudden - the application or *user* used one year when the system run on another. Which is no different than using eg a US decimal separator `.` in a European country, where the decimal separator is `,`

Comment: In fact, *using* the `IFormatProvider` helps *avoid* unexpected conversions by passing an explicit CultureInfo instead of the ambient one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know where the problem is, I just thought that maybe GUIDs are formatted inconsistently by the code because of different formatting used by default in different parts of the code.

Comment: Why do you think there *is* a problem to begin with? In the question you linked there was most likely a user error, not a .NET or C# or even Windows error. Typing the wrong year in Excel would result in the same behavior. As for the *default* behaviour for desktop or web apps, it's thoroughly documented

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, in the question I linked to `DateTime.UtcNow` was formatted with "current culture" and then year 2555 was used to create a path in blob storage.

Comment: @sharptooth because the system's or user's locale was Thai. So the code that executed `DateTime.UtcNow` got a date in the Thai calendar, which was then serialized as a Thai date